# url rewrite in php for change posts url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I want change url:

```
http://example.com/posts.php?action=view&id="a number"
```

to

```
http://example.com/posts/"a number"
```

I write these  into the .htaccess file but they don't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^posts/([0-9]+)/?$    posts.php?action=view&id=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^posts/?$    posts.php    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(posts)\.php\?action=view&id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^posts\.php$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(posts)\.php\ HTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^posts\.php$ /%1/? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(posts)/(\d+)/?$ /$1.php?action=view&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(posts)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: hi, i use this but when i go to example.com/posts/ i get 404 not found, and when i example.com/posts/13 when i write click in posts, i see this link: http://mahmoodcms.com/posts/posts.php?action=view&id=13. nneed i change my php file for change link posts.php?action=view&id=anumber?

Comment: hi, now, correct, but can you get a rewrite for posts.php to posts/ thanks.

Comment: @MahmoodHojabri Updated the post above.

Comment: @MahmoodHojabri If the reply helped, please accept it as an answer and the question will not appear as unanswered on the QnA list.

Comment: hi, thanks, can you write a discription for these code? thanks?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below in your .htaccess file

**.htaccess file code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^posts/([0-9]+)   /posts.php?action=view&id=$1    [QSA,L]
```

**QSA** means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL, it will be appended to the rewrite.

**L** means if the rule matches, don't process any more **RewriteRules** below this one.

Comment: Is **Mod_Rewrite** enable in your server?

Comment: yes, because this code is worked! RewriteRule    ^posts/?$    posts.php    [NC,L] but this code is not work: RewriteRule   ^.+/posts/([0-9]+)   posts.php?action=view&id=$1    [QSA,L]

Comment: try this `RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)$ /posts.php?action=view&id=$1 [L]`

Comment: when i right click on link and copy this with firefox i get this: http://mahmoodcms.com/posts/posts.php?action=view&id=13 and when i go to posts.php and rightclick on link i get this http://mahmoodcms.com/posts.php?action=view&id=13

Comment: test your htaccess here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/p5sHN.png

Comment: i can not go to chat because i have 1 reputation

Comment: i'm blind and can not see images. my code is: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^posts/?$    posts.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)$ /posts.php?action=view&id=$1 [L]

Comment: can you creat a file for me for change http://example.com/posts.php?action=view&id="idnumber" to http://example.com/posts/"idnumber"? thanks very much.